# fabricjs even listeners for objects in group

Tags: fabricjs

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvDraw');
var c = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 10,
  left: 0,
  fill: '#fff',
  opacity: 0.1
});
c.hasControls = true; // enable to chaneg circle size
c.hasBorders = true;
c.setOpacity(100);
c.visible = true;
c.fill = '#000';

var text = new fabric.Text("Very long text data displayed on hover", {
  width: '50px'
});
var group = new fabric.Group([c, text], {
  left: left,
  top: top
});
canvas.add(group);
```

I want to have events like text displaying on hover of the object c(circle in group). 
Tried c.on('mouse:over') but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for subTarget using `subTargetCheck:true`, on mouseover of group check added mouse:move event to canvas and check the targets if it is you circle then show the text are set `visible:false` to hide. And on mouseout remove the mouse:move event from canvas.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvDraw');
var c = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 100,
  left: 0,
  fill: '#a6ff00'
});

var text = new fabric.Text("Very long text data displayed \n on hover", {
  width: '50px',
  fill: 'green',
  visible: false
});
var group = new fabric.Group([c, text], {
  left: 20,
  top: 20,
  subTargetCheck:true,
  perPixelTargetFind:true
});
canvas.add(group);
group.on('mouseover',function(option){
  canvas.on('mouse:move',onMouseMove)
});
group.on('mouseout',function(option){
  onMouseMove();
  canvas.off('mouse:move',onMouseMove)
});

function onMouseMove(option){
 var textObj = group.getObjects()[1];
 if(option && option.subTargets[0] && (option.subTargets[0].type == 'circle')){
  if(textObj.visible) return;
  textObj.visible = true;
 }
 else {
  if(!textObj.visible) return;
  textObj.visible = false;
 }
 group.dirty = true;
 canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvDraw' width=500 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the text flicker while the cursor is moving?

Comment: @NicScozzaro as per question, I have made snipppet which on mouse move of group object if it finds circle object in group then it will show the text, if it is text then it will hide it. If you want to keep it, then here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3q76mnx/)

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for canvas DoubleClick ?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu use `mousedblclick` on group object.

Comment: Is there a way i could get that on the canvas itself instead of each and every group ?

Comment: Iam unable to handle `mousedblclick` on a group can you give me a sample fiddle please. `mousedown` works just fine but not `mousedblclick`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sundeep55555/w79yLmb6/6/  I am trying to add a new group with the `mousedblclick` for the group but it doesn't work please check `document.getElementById("group").onclick`

Comment: Not sure where I am getting it wrong should i have the event listener outside of the method? or am i missing something simple ? @Durga

Comment: @SundeepPidugu mousedblclick is got added after v2